# C++ When to use const Reference over Forwarding Reference

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference, const-reference

Consider we need to implement a function `f` with a templated argument `T t`. The function should not copy `t` and accept both `rvalues` and `lvalues`, therefore two implementations are possible:

```
template <class T>
void f(const T& t) { ... }

template <class T>
void f(T&& t) { ... }
```

If we want to change `t` inside of `f` or need to preserve the value category, we have to use the second version. So by this line of thought when and why would we go for the first option?

Comment: *So by this line of thought when and why would we go for the first option?* When you don't need to modify the value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perfect forwarding - what's it all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/perfect-forwarding-whats-it-all-about)

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica True, but I could still go for the second option. The only advantage I see in version one is explicitly stating that `t` will not change.

Comment: @Seriously Which is why you want it.  Let the compiler work for you by pointing out your mistakes instead of shipping them.

Comment: @MarekR Not really. The link seems to only give arguments why to use the second option as far as I see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forwarding reference vs const lvalue reference in template code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989511/forwarding-reference-vs-const-lvalue-reference-in-template-code)

Comment: @JulienLopez No because OP's code example is not a forwarding reference, hence no one considered this in their answers.

Comment: *"I could still go for the second option"* The first option is more convenient in some cases. E.g. if you want to know the type of the parameter, you can simply write `T` instead of `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll mainly go for the first option when you want to give strong guarantee to the clients of your function that `t` won't be changed inside of `f`. Although you can drop the `const` qualifier and still not modify `t`, it's considered good practice and good interface design to qualify as `const` a parameter if you don't change it's referred to value inside a function, plus it helps the compiler to optimize the code better.

As an extra, know that you can use `const_cast` to hack around the type safety of `const` if you really must, but recall that you're doing exactly that: getting rid of the type safety. Avoid this at all cost.

And lastly, a `const` qualifier doesn't prevent copying, you can easily do something like:

```
int main() 
{
   const int a = 3;
   int b = a; // a is copied to b
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this generic scenario, there is no reason to write both overloads.

If `f` will only observe its argument, then only the `const T&` overload is needed.

If `f` will just forward its argument to some other function, then only the `T&&` overload is needed, and will use `std::forward<T>`. (This includes the case where the function needs to retain a copy of the value, *i.e.,* forward it to a copy/move constructor.)